# Error while using an email action

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, automation

**2.1. Create OpportunityContactRole - We can't save this record because the “Update GrantReconts, when GrantContact role is added” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error occurred when the flow tried to update records: CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER: We can't save this record because the “UpdateStagesandSubStagesForHIreNow” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. Unexpected data type for emailAddressesArray: expected String[]
Error ID: 350381833-7865 (1562029241)xpected data type for emailAddressesArray: expected String[]
Error ID: 350381833-7865 (1562029241). You can look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 350381833-7866 (1065366303)look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error ID: 350381833-7866 (1065366303)**

Error in the flow while providing an email recipient in the action.

[image]

Here I have added an email of a related field.I have to receive mail to this mail id.At first I tried inputting this formula into the email address collection but I can get only till this {!$Record.Primary_Contact__r.} no email option available..How do I solve this error?

Comment: Can you remove the Comma and check if it is allowing to save as it is only single email no need to add Comma at the end

Comment: Also Can you check if your record has primary contact because of which you may get the error

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala removed the comma and tried but I cant save it,Also checked the primary contact it is present.

Comment: Are you populating the sender email as well in the send Email component? Because I don't see any other issue in the flow .

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala Thanks for the help.The issue is solved.

Comment: Can you confirm how the issue is resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

You Have "Email Address Collection" checked as an input but nothing in the collection. Which is why you are getting the error that the collection is empty and it is expecting a value. uncheck that toggle and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving input at the Email address (comma-separate), select
Recipient ID and provide $record.Primary_Contact__c. ( in this option the Recepient id should be the id of the contact, not the email)

[image]